# Writing a code for nonlinear parameter estimation problems

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, time-series, similarity, curves

I am struggling in finding a way to write a code which can let me do the following:

I have a nonlinear ODE called `fy`.

```
fy = g1*p1+g2*p2+g3*p3; % g1,g2,g3 are real-valued numbers and p1,p2,p3 are vectors
```

`g1`, `g2` and `g3` are **constants** found by the method of linear regression.

```
g1 = 591.5121
g2 = 35.1352
g3 = 107.5798
```

the vectors `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are given as follow: (sorry than I am not giving the hole vector `p1`, `p2` and `p3` since they have **1500 rows**:

```
[ p1        p2        p3] =
-0.8714   -0.0527   -0.3103
-0.3154   -0.0101    0.0874
-0.1972   -0.0029    0.1247
-0.1449   -0.0001    0.1294
-0.1151    0.0012    0.1271
-0.0959    0.0020    0.1231
-0.0824    0.0025    0.1187
-0.0723    0.0028    0.1144
-0.0646    0.0030    0.1104
-0.0584    0.0032    0.1068
-0.0533    0.0033    0.1034
-0.0491    0.0034    0.1003
-0.0455    0.0035    0.0975
-0.0425    0.0035    0.0949
-0.0398    0.0036    0.0925
-0.0375    0.0036    0.0903
-0.0355    0.0036    0.0882
-0.0336    0.0036    0.0863
-0.0320    0.0037    0.0845
-0.0305    0.0037    0.0828
-0.0292    0.0037    0.0812
-0.0280    0.0037    0.0797
-0.0268    0.0037    0.0783
-0.0258    0.0037    0.0769
-0.0249    0.0037    0.0757
-0.0240    0.0037    0.0745
-0.0232    0.0037    0.0733
-0.0224    0.0037    0.0722
-0.0217    0.0037    0.0712
-0.0211    0.0037    0.0702
   .         .          .
   .         .          .
   .         .          .
```

I am solving the `ODE` as follows:

```
fy = g1*p1+g2*p2+g3*p3;                     (1)
y= xj; % here has xj the same dim. than fy
f = @(yq)interp1(y, fy, yq);
tspan = 0:0.02:1;
x0 = 0.2;
[~, xt] = ode45(@(t,y)f(y), tspan, x0);
```

And I get a very nice curve.

My problem is: I have a `Library`:

```
Library = [L1 L2 L3]; % L1, L2, L3 are vectors of same size than p1, p2, p3
```

This `Library` contains potential triples, and ONE SET of these triples (given in row...lets say 568) can allow me to get the same nice curve I am getting from (1). In other words, if I change `g1`, `g2` and `g3` with `l1`, `l2` and `l3` (which are found in the row 586 from `Library`) I should have almost the same results as in (1).

I need to find a way to find this SET of triples!

The only information to my disposal is the information from (1) and the curve I get. It would be awful if I have to compare all the curves to the one I get from (1)... because my `Library` has 1500 triples which implies 1500 curves... After I have my triples I could solve the following system in the same way as I did it with (1).

```
 fy = l1*p1+l2*p2+l3*p3;                 (2)
 y= xj; % xj % has the same dim than fy
 f = @(yq)interp1(y, fy, yq);
 tspan = 0:0.02:1;
 x0 = 0.2;
 [~, xt2] = ode45(@(t,y)f(y), tspan, x0);
```

`fy` from (1) should be approximate to `fy` from (2).

some more info: From linear regression I was supposed to get a set of triples that are/exits in my library, but this is not the case... my system is, because of this, sloppy. For this reason I have to find a way to connect in some way these two outputs. (the g's and the l's).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `dsearchn` to find the closest triplet.

```
x = rand(1000,3);
xi = rand(1,3);
k = dsearchn(x,xi);
```

Alternatively, you may compare all the 1500 generated curves with the original one. There are several techniques such as the ones described here [how to find the similarity between two curves and the score of similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373062/how-to-find-the-similarity-between-two-curves-and-the-score-of-similarity)

Comment: Hi @Macduff, thanks for tour quick answer, I will try your suggestion and check the link you are posting.

Comment: Hi @Macduff, I have examined your suggestion (and try it). My problem is that none of my `g`-values are/exists in `Library`. In other words, I don't have any `xi` in my `x`. Can I still use `dsearchn`?

Comment: You mean that you can't find any closest triplet? You can also try a distance of your choice and find its minimum (minimum of the euclidian distance for example)

Comment: Hi again @Macduff. Yes, I do not have any triple which is close to my `g`-values. That is my problem, I get a nice curve with the `g's` and I have to find the `l`-values that can help me reproduce the same curve. Nevertheless, `g` and `l` doesn't need to be close to each other. And the are not.

Comment: By the way, I have try this problem where I have control of the `g's` and `l's` and it works, but I need to find a way to make it work with out manipulating my `g`-values.